# Bottom node in stackpane disappearing

Tags: java, javafx

Each stack pane is supposed to have two nodes. However the bottom node disappears outside the for loop for the first 2 indices in the stack pane array.

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    GridPane images;
    StackPane[] stackPane;
    ImageView cardBack;
    ImageView[] cardImages;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        images = new GridPane(); images.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        images.setVgap(5); images.setHgap(5);

        cardBack = new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("images/b1fv.gif")));
        cardImages = new ImageView[]{
                new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("images/c1.gif"))),
                new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("images/c2.gif"))),
                new ImageView(new Image(new FileInputStream("images/c3.gif")))
        };

        final Button[] flip = new Button[cardImages.length];
        stackPane = new StackPane[cardImages.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < cardImages.length; i++) {
            stackPane[i] = new StackPane();
            stackPane[i].getChildren().addAll(cardBack, cardImages[i]);

            images.add(stackPane[i], i, 0, 1, 1);
            flip[i] = new Button("Flip");
            GridPane.setHalignment(flip[i], HPos.CENTER);
            images.add(flip[i], i, 1, 1, 1);

            // Debug
            System.out.println(stackPane[i].getChildren().toString());

            final int j = i;
            flip[j].setOnAction(event -> doFlip(j));
        }

        // Debug
        System.out.println("");
        for (StackPane pane : stackPane)
            System.out.println(pane.getChildren().toString());

        stage.setTitle("Assignment 11");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(images, 500,200));
        stage.show();
    }

    void doFlip(int loc) {
        // Debug
        System.out.println("");
        for (StackPane pane : stackPane)
            System.out.println(pane.getChildren().toString());

        ObservableList<Node> children = stackPane[loc].getChildren();
        Node topNode = children.get(children.size()-1);
        topNode.toBack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
[ImageView@5e1bc54a[styleClass=image-view], ImageView@25389181[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@5e1bc54a[styleClass=image-view], ImageView@ff7cf97[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@5e1bc54a[styleClass=image-view], ImageView@18b8669d[styleClass=image-view]]

[ImageView@25389181[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@ff7cf97[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@5e1bc54a[styleClass=image-view], ImageView@18b8669d[styleClass=image-view]]

[ImageView@25389181[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@ff7cf97[styleClass=image-view]]
[ImageView@5e1bc54a[styleClass=image-view], ImageView@18b8669d[styleClass=image-view]]
```

Inside the for loop it displays all objects. However, outside the loop in does not display the bottom nodes except for the last element of array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the same Node instance to multiple parents!

In the top of your loop you have the following line:

```
stackPane[i].getChildren().addAll(cardBack, cardImages[i]);
```

The `cardBack` Node would be added to all StackPanes, but since it can only have one parent, it will be removed from the previous. Javafx has provided a way to reuse Image resources though (which is I imagine the thing you want to achieve). Instead of creating one `ImageView`, you can cache the `Image` instance passes in the `ImageView` constructor. E.g:

```
cardBack = new Image(new FileInputStream("images/b1fv.gif"));
// some stuff
for (int i = 0; i < cardImages.length; i++) {
    stackPane[i] = new StackPane();
    stackPane[i].getChildren().addAll(new ImageView(cardBack) , cardImages[i]);
    // rest of the loop
}
```

If you use the `Image` and `ImageView` as described above, things will work correctly.